# Reversing a negative number in Python

Tags: python, slice

Using `slice` method in `Python` we are able to reverse strings and numbers easily. However, how could it be done when the number is negative?

```
def reverse(x):
    string = str(x)
    return int(string[::-1])

print(reverse(-123))
```

Gives an error as it returns `321-`

**EDIT:**

Now let's have two more assumptions:

1. If the reversed number is not within `[−2^31,  2^31 − 1]` it
   should return 0.
2. For numbers like `120`, it should return `21` as its reverse.

Now, how can we reverse `-120` into `-21`?

Comment: So should `reverse(-12)` return `21` or `-21`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey should be -21 as it is reversed of -12.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you want to preserve the sign, try this:

```
def reverse(x):
    ans = int(str(x)[::-1]) if x >= 0 else -int(str(-x)[::-1])
    return ans if -2**31 <= ans <= 2**31 - 1 else 0
```

It works as expected for all the edge cases introduced by the new requirements:

```
reverse(321)
=> 123
reverse(-321)
=> -123
reverse(120)
=> 21
reverse(-120)
=> -21
reverse(7463847412)
=> 2147483647
reverse(8463847412)
=> 0
reverse(-8463847412)
=> -2147483648
reverse(-9463847412)
=> 0
```

Comment: Instead of `(1 if x > 0 else -1)` you could also go `(x > 0 or -1)` -- but that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @palivek I like that your answer is shorter, but I'll stick with my approach. Yours is a bit hacky, abusing the fact that `True` can be interpreted as `1` :) .

Comment: How can you say that he expected `-321`?

Comment: That's my assumption (seems like the most logical thing to do), I clarified that at the beginning.

Comment: Your assumption is indeed right. What if we have -120? it should be  reversed as -21

Comment: @lonesome my solution already works like that: `reverse(-120) == -21`

Comment: @lonesome I modified my solution to include the restriction on the valid output range. Short and sweet.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the unwrapped, simplified code to make it easier to understand the answer:

```
def int_reverser(test):
    if test >= 0:
        answer = int(str(test)[::-1])
    else:
        answer = -int(str(-test)[::-1])
    if -2**31 <= answer <= 2**31 - 1:
        return answer
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited

You can check ,if your number is negative then add `-` behind the output. You will get the expected output.
Therefore you code will be like:

```
def reverse(x):
    y = ""
    if int(x) <= -1:y="-";x = int(x)*-1
    output =  int(y+str(x)[::-1])
    if output >= -2**31 and output <= 2**31 - 1:return output
    else: return 0
    
print(reverse(-123))
```

Testing:

```
>>> reverse(-123)
-321
>>> reverse(123)
321
>>> reverse(-120)
-21
>>> reverse(120)
21
>>> reverse(123)
321
>>> reverse(-74634545484744)
0
>>> reverse(74634545484744)
0
```

It is also very simple and understandable.

Comment: Now this works for negative numbers, and fails for positive numbers.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Check now.

Comment: Now it's removing the sign, I don't think that's the proper behavior. Please check my answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I think he expected `321` , i.e. removing the sign.

Comment: I dont. Please forgive me as I forgot to make the expected output clear.

Comment: @lonesome Done, check now.

Comment: @lonesome You can check now , the output of `reverse(-120)` will be equal to `-21`.

Comment: I'm afraid it fails for overflowed Integers

Comment: @lonesome Check Now. I was in a hurry before.